# What is the difference between External Column vs an Output Column?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, metadata, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to learn SSIS and stuck on what exactly are External Columns and Output Columns?  It seems like all that metadata could be stored in just one... unless there is another reason I'm not understanding.  If someone could explain what each really is in clear language then maybe I could figure this out.

I've read explanation on this site.  Read explanations on the MSDN site.  Searched answers on Google.  Read about this in a book titled "Professional Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Integration Services".

Comment: (using Visual Studio 2017) In the Advanced Editor for OLE DB Source under the "Input and Output Properties" tab... there are no inputs?  Is the External Columns considered the input or is input optional?  So confusing.

Answer (score 3):

- **External Columns** live outside of the environment you are working (Excel, text files, databases).

  Are SOURCES and DESTINATIONS.
- **Input Columns** are columns inside the environment that go into an object (SOURCE, TRANSFORM or DESTINATION)
- **Output Columns** are inside the environment that exit an object (SOURCE, TRANSFORM, or DESTINATION)

External Columns are initially converted to Input Columns a source object expects.

External Columns do not match [out of synch] means your source changed somehow. Usually a column name or a data type changed.

Similarly, Output Columns of a destination lead to External Columns.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  I have an OLE DB Source object that is connected to a specific table.  In the Advanced Editor under Input and Output Properties it lists the OLE DB Source Output with External and Output Columns.  If I'm understanding your explanation, the External Columns are the input... if so, then why are they inside the OLE DB Source Output?  (wish I could post an image of it).

Comment: ... shouldn't there be a section titled "OLE DB Source Input"?

Comment: I think I see it now.  The Source Object only lists outputs and The Destination Object only lists inputs.  The input for the Source Object is the Source Object that has made itself a copy of the table... just as the Output Object is the Output.

Answer (score 1):

In simple words:

- **External Columns:** represent the metadata of external data sources
- **Output Columns:** represent the metadata of the columns used within the data flow task

Additional information can be found at:

- [SSIS Data types: Change from the Advanced Editor vs Data Conversion Transformations](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-data-types-change-from-the-advanced-editor-vs-data-conversion-transformations/)

Comment: Would you know if implicit conversions are performed on External Columns or are External Columns exact copies of the source table and any implicit conversions are in the Output Column?

Comment: @KendrickKeeton implicit conversion can be done on both External and Output column. As I know, data types must match between External and Output columns.